# Creating hierarchical relationships like REST Api with Django

Tags: python, django, rest

New to Django. I know there is Django to Swagger generator is there but what I want is other way around.

I want to create REST API:

```
GET api/job/{id} 
POST api/job/{id}

GET api/job/{id}/status
POST api/job/{id}/status
```

I don't think this project needs relational database, but for now I'm stuck with it. My model file looks like:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    job_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    some_arg = models.TextField()


class ChoicesEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls)


class Status(models.Model):

    class JobStatus(ChoicesEnum):
        NOT_STARTED = 0
        IN_PROGRESS = 1
        SUCCEEDED = 2
        FAILED = 3

    job_id = models.OneToOneField(
        Job,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    job_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=JobStatus.choices())
```

But I'm not sure how am I supposed to create views for those two such a way they will be related. Sounds simple but can't wrap my head around.

Comment: Your `Status` model is wrong. The `OneToOneField` should be called `job` (not `job_id`) and it should not be the primary key. I'm not sure what your problem is. If you have a `job` instance, then `job.status` is the related `Status` instance. Conversely, if you have a `Status` instance, then `status.job` will be the `Job` instance (assuming your renamed to `job`). In the view, create the job first, save it, then create the status, assigning the previously saved job to it.

Comment: why does the `Status` field needs to be `job`, it is related to `Job`.  My problem is: how to write Views? Just usual one like two `GenericAPIView` for Status and Job? And write `Urls.py` with pattern?

Comment: With your current model, `status.job_id` is a `Job` instance not the id of that job. Under the hoods, Django creates a `job_id_id` field. See why it should be called `job`?

Comment: Ah, Django creates primary key for each table, is that why I'll have `job_id_id`?

Comment: You now mention `GenericAPIView`, which isn't part of Django. Are you using Django REST Framework? In which case yes, write a Serializer that combines the two models (e.g. takes `Job` as a model and adds the status field of the related `Status`) and use the regular generic views to read and write with the serializer.

Comment: No, that's a different thing. You should let django create the primary key (that will just be `id` and the reason you should not set primary_key=True in the job relation). But `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField` and `ManyToManyField` are references to the instances, not the ids. So `Status.job_id` in your case is actually a `Job` object. You can do `status.job_id.some_arg`. So it really should be `status.job`. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)